# using a typedef from another class in a circular manner

Tags: c++, syntax, circular-dependency

This is a question to see the limits of the C++ language.

Most circular class dependencies can be solved with forward declarations and pointers.

But I wonder if this can be solved somehow:

```
struct Y; // forward declaring Y does not solve the problem

struct X {
  using T = int;
  using Other = Y::T; //error: incomplete type 'Y' named in nested name specifier
};

struct Y {
  using T = float;
  using Other = X::T;
};
```

Parsing it by a human eye, you can easily see that in this code `X::Other` could trivially be understood as `float` because `Y::T` does not depend on anything. However I do not know of any syntax that would allow to "forward declare a typedef", something like `typename Y::T = float;` (but there are always unexplored dark corners of C++) or any method or idiom that would allow the above typedefs.

So is there a technique to resolve the above? (specifically: each class using the other class's typedef - wthout moving the typedef outside the class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make X a template struct. Something like this.

```
template <typename YType>
struct X {
  using T = int;
  using Other = typename YType::T;
};

struct Y {
  using T = float;
  using Other = X<Y>::T;
};

int main()
{
    X<Y> x;
}
```

It is not a perfect solution, but when you have corner cases like this, sometimes you need to do hacks.

Comment: yep, that's what I was thinking. Curious if other solutions exist.